# Is it right on the side of designer to use Slider on the main page of website?

Tags: website-design

I see a lot of templates coming with an massive slider on the top of the main page and as I was about to design my website I wanted to know if it's good for the design and UX .
And as I googled it many sites says it's an bad idea but I wanted more idea of how it affects UX.

Comment: Do you have any examples and your purpose to use them?

Comment: [Should I Use A Carousel?](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/)